# Trying to remove kernels

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

I am trying to remove old kernels in an encrypted system.  I am getting kernels marked for purge, but installed after my efforts.

I start with removing leftover temporary files from previous kernel updates

```
$ sudo rm -rv ${TMPDIR:-/var/tmp}/mkinitramfs-*
```

My current version number is 4.4.0-127-generic

Here is my list currently after several attempts. I'm trying to keep 127 (my current version, and 124)

```
$ dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+'
pi  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic              4.4.0-112.135                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
pi  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic              4.4.0-116.140                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
pi  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic              4.4.0-119.143                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
pi  linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic              4.4.0-121.145                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-122-generic              4.4.0-122.146                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic              4.4.0-124.148                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic              4.4.0-127.153                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

So, say I try to remove 4.4.0-119

I free space in boot by removing initrd.img file

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -d -k 4.4.0-119-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
```

I try purging the kernal

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic

dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic:
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (= 4.4.0-119.143).

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
(Reading database ... 513541 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-127-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-124-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-122-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-122-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
done
Purging configuration files for linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
```

Doing this changes the status of the kernel to pi.  This is the method I used previously to remove old kernels.  I'm not sure what changed here.

Comment: have you tried purging from apt: sudo apt purge linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic

Comment: And thank you for the edits.  I realized after the fact what a nightmare that looked.

Comment: I had followed the commands in this answer under the section for "Safely Removing Old Kernels" previously.  It suggested purging from dpkg.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: Read the error message carefully: dpkg is telling you exactly what the problem is - there is *another* package you must remove first. Apt resolves these dependencies and removes in the correct order, dpkg does not - you must manually remove in the correct order.

Comment: Using `--purge` vs `--remove` for packages that lack any files in /etc may be a habit, but it's not a great habit. In this case, both will do exactly the same thing, so no harm done. Some new user mistakenly believe `--purge` to be a kind of 'force', and it's important that we point out it's definitely not.

Comment: Don't use `sudo rm` in /boot to free space. That often creates more complex problems later - strange, confusing errors when apt and grub cannot find files that they expect to be present.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message you are getting:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic:
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (= 4.4.0-119.143).
```

It tells you that after removal of these package the package `linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic` would have an unmet dependency. So the solution to your problem should be to also remove this package as it belongs to the kernel you are trying to remove.

Try this command:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing from apt:

```
sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
```